How to move back one line after printing something in the console
I made this program that imitates how brute-forcing is shown in movies. how it works: it asks the user for some text and then in the console it will print the letters one by one until the letter of the text is matched. this goes on for all the letters of the text.
import time
import os

capital = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
lower = [element.lower() for element in capital]
text = input("Enter your text: ")

for index, char in enumerate(text):
    index = 0
    
    while True:
        if str(char) == lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            break
        elif str(char) != lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(lower[index], end='\r')
        index += 1
        
    print(char, end='\r')

But I have come across a problem. The expected output after the program has ran is:
enter your text: def def

But I receive:
enter your text: def  
d   
e   
f

I know I can just use the end='' or end='\r' at line 20 for disabling new line or adding a backspace. but both of them don't work.
For example if I use end='' the output is:
Enter your text: def 

fa

or end='\r':
Enter your text: def 

f


Works for me on Linux. I mean, all letters appear in the same position, not on new lines. And you get a crash if the input contains something that is not a letter.

\r returns to the beginning of the line.  Use \b (backspace). It also requires correct terminal support. flush=True is needed because terminals generally don't flush to the screen until a newline.  My version works in Windows cmd.exe and should work in Linux shells as well:
import time
import string

tries = ''' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'''
text = input('Enter your text: ')

for char in text:
    for match in tries:
        print(f'{match}', end='', flush=True)
        if char != match:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            print('\b', end='', flush=True)
        else:
            break

Output (each letter rolling until matched):
Enter your text: Python is #1
Python is #1


You could try
import time
import os

capital = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
lower = [element.lower() for element in capital]
text = input("Enter your text: ")

n=len("Enter your text: ")+len(text)+1
print(f"\033[1A\033[{n}C", flush=True, end='')
for index, char in enumerate(text):
    index = 0

    while True:
        if str(char) == lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            break
        elif str(char) != lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(lower[index], end='\b', flush=True)
        index += 1

    print(char, end='')
print()

I say "try" since what others told you (\b is not guaranteed to work) is even more true for those ANSI escape sequence I use.
The proper way to do that would be to use curses or something like that, that detects what the terminal is, and does it best with what control sequence the terminal supports.
But, well, nowadays, those ANSI sequences are quite widely supported (but not universally. Not with oled display of upython machines, obviously. Not with jupyter notebooks. Not for embedded terminal of many IDE. Etc.), and I feel that you are looking more for some "hacking trick" than for a proper way to do that (is there really a proper way?)
The main things I do is

What others already did: going back to the left between each trial of a char, with \b. Adding flush=True so that it has an animation effect; and just printing with end='' when you change the character.

Since you wanted to have the result next to your input, and, after all, the very title of your question is "going back one line", I start by going back 1 line, with the 2 ansi sequences \033[1A and \033[21C


\033[1A does what is your litteral question: going up one line.
But that is not enough. Because what you are trying to undo with that "up" is the carriage return typed by the user when input the string. But that carriage return effect was not just to go down a line. It was also going back at the beginning of the line. And this can't be undone easily.
So what I do is compute (n) the position of the second def (which is the size of the prompt text, plus the size of what users typed. plus 1 for the space you want). Which here is n=21. And then, with f-string here, typing \033[21C meaning "going 21 chars to the right".
There are many other ways to do that. For example you also have \033[y;xH which is roughly what was called gotoxy in very old languages (back in the time when some languages bothers with display, which they shouldn't since that is a matter of I/O devices).
There are also ways to "ask" the terminal to get its positions, and go back there, instead of computing position with len. And to suppress "echo" (the fact that the terminal writes what the user types), so that you do the echo yourself, and therefore choose to not echo the carriage return typed by the user.
But, well, all of them suffer from the same problem: they are not standard. You can't assume, if this is meant to be distributed, that user terminal has it.
But since you were already trying with things that you can't assume exist, ...
Again, if this is more serious than I feel it is, and need to be embedded in a distributed code (meant not to be run on your machine — in which cas, if it works...—) you should have a look at curses.
EDIT : Side note
This is not related to your question, but I can't help

You don't really need a list of strings containing a single letter. Even letting aside fact that you could play with chr and ord to avoid enumerating the alphabet, there is already a simpler array (well indexable container) of letters: that is a string

capital="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

would have done the same.
(With a very important difference but that doesn't matter here: strings are immutable. So you couldn't modify capital[2]. But since you don't do it)
Then
lower=capital.lower()


You don't need to cast your char to a string. It is already a string. Even with my method (which, in other languages, would not have been an array of strings, like your capital, but an array of char. But in python, practically, a char is a string of length 1)

So
if str(char) == lower[index]:

→
if char==lower[index]:

(and other similar lines)

You don't need that enumerate. Anyway, you overwrite index first thing, so why computing that index?

So
for index, char in enumerate(text):

→
for char in text:


You can't trully "Move back" because of how console works, but I can propose a rather radical solution: clear console screen (i.e. buffer) everytime you change something, and rewrite what was written but with additional elements that may change:
import time
import os

capital = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
lower = [element.lower() for element in capital]

os.system("cls")
text = input("Enter your text: ")

os.system("cls")
print(f"Enter your text: {text}")
history = ""

for index, char in enumerate(text):
    index = 0

    while True:
        if str(char) == lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            break
        elif str(char) != lower[index]:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            os.system("cls")
            print(f"Enter your text: {text} {history + lower[index]}")
        index += 1
        
    os.system("cls")
    print(f"Enter your text: {text} {history + char}")
    history += char

Above code achieves what you would like to, it clears console screen everytime something is changed. For little brute-forcing effect (BFE) history variable stores the actual word being built during the so called BFE animation.
There are many questions in my mind about the codebase, but here you have some kind of solution.

Why the system("cls")? That only works on Windows. If OP wants to keep any other text on the screen, this approach breaks anyway.

Well, yes, you can. Not with pure standard ways, sure. But then, os.system('cls') is even less standard (it is guaranteed not to work on most machines, since, nowadays, most machines are unix variants, if you count tablets, phones, etc.)

Yeah, maybe I should mention that for linux it should be os.system('clear')
